# Thrift make error libtool: eval: unexpected EOF

Tags: c, thrift, scribe

I'm trying to setup thrift-0.9.2 for scribe on Ubuntu 14.04 and I'm running into the following problem during the build process. Does anyone know how to fix this?

> /bin/bash ../../libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=link g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -g -O2 -std=c++11   -o thrift thrift-main.o thrift-md5.o thrift-t_generator.o thrift-t_typedef.o thrift-parse.o thrift-t_c_glib_generator.o thrift-t_cpp_generator.o thrift-t_java_generator.o thrift-t_json_generator.o thrift-t_as3_generator.o thrift-t_csharp_generator.o thrift-t_py_generator.o thrift-t_rb_generator.o thrift-t_perl_generator.o thrift-t_php_generator.o thrift-t_erl_generator.o thrift-t_cocoa_generator.o thrift-t_st_generator.o thrift-t_ocaml_generator.o thrift-t_hs_generator.o thrift-t_xsd_generator.o thrift-t_html_generator.o thrift-t_js_generator.o thrift-t_javame_generator.o thrift-t_delphi_generator.o thrift-t_go_generator.o thrift-t_gv_generator.o thrift-t_d_generator.o thrift-t_lua_generator.o -lfl libparse.a

```
../../libtool: eval: line 6459: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'

../../libtool: eval: line 6460: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Comment: Did you see [this](http://thrift.apache.org/docs/install/debian)?

Comment: I wonder also if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33944237/473305) is relevant.

Answer (score 2):

I'm trying to setup thrift v0.10.0 and have ran into the same problem just like yours:

```
../../../libtool: eval: line 6458: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
../../../libtool: eval: line 6459: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

In `libtool`, line 6458 and line 6459 is:

```
6457        eval sys_lib_search_path=\"$sys_lib_search_path_spec\"
6458        eval sys_lib_dlsearch_path=\"$sys_lib_dlsearch_path_spec\"
6459
```

and i changed `"` to `'`, then it comes:

```
6457        eval sys_lib_search_path='\$sys_lib_search_path_spec'
6458        eval sys_lib_dlsearch_path='\$sys_lib_dlsearch_path_spec'
6459
```

Until now, i have fixed the problem, maybe you can have a try!

Comment: I've had the same problem in the 7977 and 7978 lines. It worked for me.

Comment: It worked for me in AWS EC2 (AWS AMI - Centos) while compiling SOX.

Comment: It worked for me in AWS EC2 (AWS AMI - Centos) while compiling SOX. Steps I followed. 1. Downloaded the SOX 4.4.2 source code. 2. extracted the source code. 3. moved inside the extracted directory. 4. fired the command ./configure 5. fired the command make -s 6. Issue poped-up 7. Edited the file libtool as mentioned above 8. rerun sudo make -s. (it ran for half an hour) 9. fired the command sudo make install 10. verified by firing sox command on the prompt. Done